# Why my user model is not saving even after the code is running successfully

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**I want to create a social media web app. I am currently working on the signup functionality**
*Please help me find why my user model is not saving*

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
import string
import random

# Create your models here.


def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if ProfileUser.objects.filter(user_name=code).count() == 0:
            break

    return code


class ProfileUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    user_name = models.SlugField(
        unique=True, max_length=30, default=generate_unique_code)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

My SignUp View

```
class signUpView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            user_name = request.GET.get("name")
            password = request.GET.get("password")
            email = request.GET.get("email")
            first_name = request.GET.get("first_name")
            last_name = request.GET.get("last_name")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({"Invalid Data": "Not Enough Data"}, 
            status=status.HTTP_206_PARTIAL_CONTENT)
        user = ProfileUser(email=email, user_name=user_name,
                       first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, password=password)
        user.save()
        return Response({"User Created": {
            "name": user_name, "email": email, "password": password
        }}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I am a beginner in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to define a custom model manager.

Add `objects = ProfileUserManager()` after `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in your model.

Then create a new module in the same app **manager.py** and create a new manager class `ProfileUserManager` for `ProfileUser()`.

This is how your **manager.py** module must look like (remember to import `ProfileUser` from your **models.py**)-

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class ProfileUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, user_name):

        user = ProfileUser(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name, 
            user_name = mobile_number, 
            password  = password
        )

        
        # Encrypt password before storing.
        user.set_password(password)

        
        # Save the object to the model.
        user.save(using = self._db)

        
        # Return newly created object's string representation.
        return user
```

Finally, this is how your **models.py** should look like (remember to import `ProfileUserManager` from your **manager.py**).

```
import string
import random

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser


def generate_unique_code():
    length = 6

    while True:
        code = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=length))
        if ProfileUser.objects.filter(user_name=code).count() == 0:
            break

    return code


class ProfileUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    user_name = models.SlugField(
        unique=True, max_length=30, default=generate_unique_code)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    objects = ProfileUserManager()
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

Comment: @pranav hopefully this will help.

Comment: I am having another error which is saying AttributeError: 'ProfileUserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

Comment: If you you are using the command `python manage.py createsuperuser` then in that case you will have to add another method in your manager class to create superuser with your custom user model. However, this is a different problem not related to the question you have asked. You can create a new question specific to your new issue.

Comment: If any of the provided solutions has worked for you then please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: are you using cli cmd `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ProfileUser.objects.create(**{'email'=email, 'user_name'=user_name,
                   'first_name'=first_name, 'last_name'=last_name, 'password'=password})
```

instead:

```
user.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, I have already got the answer